# change the format of a cell when we have a variable

Tags: vb.net, variables, format

I want to change the format of a cell when I have a variable for this cell.E.x I want to write M= 20 kg inside a cell when we have 20 as a variable

Following simple code doesn't work in excel vb.

Dim Mass#: 
Mass = 20: 
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""M=  ""& Mass &"" kg"""

If I replace Mass by 20 it works,  but doesn't work with the variable inside vb.

Let me know if you can find what's wrong!

Comment: Is your code really all on one line like that?

Comment: Unless you have good reason, keep every statement on a separate line.

Comment: Thanks Derek and my friend,
Derek, it's just few lines of main code. I am going to simplify it.

My friend thanks for your answer. Last night I did the same but didn't work. Today, I used your answer and fortunately it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub test()
Dim Mass
Mass = 20
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "M= " & Mass & " kg"
End Sub
```